# How can I mark a radio button as checked using Perl?

Tags: perl, forms, radio-button, checked

I try to create a form that can save a person's form data so that he can later finish completing the form. I have no problem to save the data to an external file and I know that it would be easy to do what I try to do if the user was permitted to save his data only once a full page form was completed. However, I want to be able to save the data of the form at any time, even if one of multiple pages have not been fully completed. Also, I like to use my own html scripting through my Perl scripts instead of calling CGI.pm form commands.

So the user saves his incomplete data at the end of a session and log in with a password at a later time to retrieve his data. So I retrieve data from the external file based on the password using

```
#--------------------------------------------
open(INFO, "MYTEXTFILE.txt");
   @data = <INFO>;
close(INFO);
#--------------------------------------------
foreach $key (@data)  
{  
  ($aaa1,$aaa2,$aaa3,$aaa4,$aaa5,$e)=split(/,/,$key);
}
```

And then I try to input the available data back into the html form. This is pretty easy when data have been collected with text-boxes:

```
 print"
 <p>Your response is: input type='text' name='aaa1' value='$aaa1' <\p>";
```

But more tricky when it is a radiobutton. I use:

```
 print"
 <table width='600' align='center' cellpadding='3'>
 <tr bgcolor=''>
           td bgcolor=''>1. Question #1                     
 </td>
 <td>1
 <input name='aaa1' type='radio' value='1'"; if ($aaa1==1) {print " CHECKED ";} print"/>/td>
 <td>2
 <input name='aaa1' type='radio' value='2'"; if ($aaa1==2) {print " CHECKED ";} print" />/td>
 <td>3
 <input name='aaa1' type='radio' value='3'"; if ($aaa1==3) {print " CHECKED ";} print" />/td>
 <td>4
 <input name='aaa1' type='radio' value='4'"; if ($aaa1==4) {print " CHECKED ";} print" />/td>
<td>5
<input name='aaa1' type='radio' value='5'"; if ($aaa1==5) {print " CHECKED ";} print" />/td>
</tr>
</table>
";
```

Is there a more convenient or handy way to do it?

Comment: ***I like to use my own html scripting through my perl scripts instead of calling cgi.pm form commands.*** *Sigh!* You do not know enough to know what you do not know. Giving you fish would not be the right thing to do. Use `CGI.pm` and any one of the many excellent template processing modules.

Comment: the code look a bit screwed up. Please keep regular text out of the code section.

Comment: @Sinan - I'm kinda willing to give him the benefit of the doubt - since he knows about GGI.pm he might be on a roll to create his own web solutions... somewhat futile practically but potentially VERY rewarding knowledge-and-experience wise... (having created CGI frameworks for both C and Perl back when, I can attest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there's an easier way.

```
foreach my $value (1,2,3,4,5) {
    my $checked = ($aaa1 == $value) ? "CHECKED " : "";
    print "<td>$value <input name='aaa1' type='radio' value='$value' $checked/></td>\n";
}
```

However, if you insist on hand-rolling your own templating solution (as opposed to using a [great number of existing Perl templating ones](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2001/08/21/templating.html)), you should do it the RIGHT way. Have generic methods for various input types, etc...

Also, as others have pointed out in comments, there's a REASON for separating code from HTML via a templating solution - it greatly simplifies maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Your output contains almost the same text and code repeating 5 times. Using a `for` loop would be more convenient.